# Get total count of files in resource folder - SwiftUI

Tags: ios, xcode, swiftui

**OUTLINE**

I have a resource folder with multiple subdirectories. In each subdirectory there are multiple .pdfs. It looks like this:

[image]

I also have a data model that stores the name of the top resource folder as well as an array that has all subdirectory resource folders names that looks like this:

```
struct ProductModel: Identifiable {
    var id = UUID()
    var headerTitle: String
    var application: [String]
 }   

let productData: [ProductModel] = [
    ProductModel(
        headerTitle: "DMA-80 evo",
        application: ["All", "Beverages","Chemicals", "Clinical", "Coal", "Cosmetics", "Energy","Environmental", "Geochemistry"],
    ),
]
```

In my first view I list all applications, if the user selects an application it is stored in my `ObservableObject` that you can see here:

```
    class selectedApplication: ObservableObject {
    @Published var selectedApplication = "All"
    @Published var selectedProduct = ""
}


struct ProductList2: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var selectedOption = selectedApplication()
    var products: [ProductModel] = productData
    
    var body: some View {
        ScrollView(.horizontal){
            HStack{
                ForEach(applicationsArray, id: \.self) { item in
                    Button(action: {
                        self.selectedOption.selectedApplication = item
                    }) {
                        Text(item)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I then navigate to a second view and list all `pdfs` that are in the folder that matches the selected application. For example, if Beverages is selected, when navigating to the second page it would display `Fruit Juice, Spirit, Sugar & Wine` in a list. This is all working perfectly.

**PROBLEM**

I am trying to do 2 things here.

1. I want to get a total count of all pdfs inside all subdirectories
2. I also have an option where the user can select `All`. This will display all `pdfs` that belong to `DMA-80 eve`. What I would like to do is list all pdfs in a grouped menu list with the section headers to be the names of the subdirectory folders (ie. Beverages, Chemicals).

This is what I have but I cannot work out the next steps.

```
struct ProductTab5NoteRow: View {
    
    @ObservedObject var application: selectedApplication
    @State var pdfURL: URL?
    
    var product: ProductModel
    
    var body: some View {
        List{
            let bundleLoc = product.headerTitle + "/" + application.selectedApplication
            let pdfs = Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension: "pdf", subdirectory: bundleLoc) ?? []
            
            ForEach(pdfs, id: \.self) { pdf in
                Button(action: {
                    self.pdfURL = pdf
                }, label: {
                    VStack(alignment: .leading) {
                        Text((pdf.lastPathComponent ?? "").dropLast(4))
                        Text(application.selectedApplication)
                    }
                })
            }
        }
    }
}
```

- `totalCount` returns nil as I am unsure how to look into each folder add add it to an array?
- I have managed to list all the subdirectory names however no pdf names.

Any help would be much appreciated as I am totally lost. Thank you.

Comment: That’s because the method you use only returns urls in the given sub directory and not in any further sub levels.

Comment: I assumed it would look in all subdirectories automatically. Does that mean it needs to in a for loop iterate through each subdirectory?

Comment: Bundles are immutable at runtime. So actually you are supposed to **know** the number of PDF files.

Comment: Okay. Are you saying that I should hardcode the total count into the data struct instead?

Comment: Yes, I am. You could write a bash script which counts the number of files once with `find`

Answer (score 0):

> totalCount returns nil as I am unsure how to look into each folder add add it to an array?

I you copy resources into application bundle with default Xcode copy bundle resources phase, then all resource files are located flat in your application bundle, ie. there are no subfolders, that's why you get 0 for `pdfCount`.

You need to remove resources from target copy bundle resources phase and create custom copy resources phase which would copy your custom folders with pdf files.

Once such subdirectories appear in application bundle (you can verify this by looking inside application bundle in Finder) next method starts working

```
Bundle.main.urls(forResourcesWithExtension:... , subdirectory:...)
```

Here is in result how it should look in Xcode & application bundle in Finder

[image: demo]

> I have managed to list all the subdirectory names however no pdf names.

As soon as you fulfil previous this one will start working automatically.

Comment: Thank you for your detailed response. I have updated my question to explain better how it is setup as some of this is already working. Would you be able to take a look please.